# freeradius 3.0.17 rlm_rest parsing json response

Tags: json, rest, api, restful-authentication, freeradius

I'm trying to authenticate RADIUS Requests against a RESTful API (provided by Customer) using rlm_rest.

The problem I am facing is that
response JSON format (of REST API provided by Customer), is different from rlm_rest default format (indicated in [etc/raddb/mods-enabled/rest](https://gist.github.com/nemesisdesign/c72d53d5c9bbfee4c03f1f2cb9afc7cb)).

My Virtual Server configuration as below:

### Default

```
authorize {
...
...
rest
if (ok) {
    update control {
        Auth-Type := rest
        }
    }
}
```

### mods-enabled/rest

```
authorize {
    uri = "https://3rd-party-API/auth"
    method = 'post'
    body = 'json'
    chunk = 0
    tls = ${..tls}
    data = '{
        "code": 1,
        "identifier": %I,
        "avps": {
            "User-Name": ["%{User-Name}"],
            "NAS-IP-Address": ["%{NAS-IP-Address}"],
            "Called-Station-Id": ["%{Called-Station-Id}"],
            "Calling-Station-Id": ["%{Calling-Station-Id}"],
            "NAS-Identifier": ["%{NAS-Identifier}"]
        }
    }'
}
```

## Result

/sbin/radiusd -Xxx

HTTP response code

```
200
```

JSON Body

```
{
    "code": "2",
    "identifier": "91",
    "avps": {
        "Customer-Attributes": "Hello"
        ...
        ...
        "Acct-Interim-Interval": "300"
    }
}
```

The JSON structure is different from the example, and xlat parse
    "code"
    "identifier"
    "avps"

And, of course, xlat finds no attributes match with the dictionary, while it cannot find "avps" and won't dig deeper.

So I was wondering is there anyway to either

1. Define the response JSON structure for xlat to parsing
2. Insert a "is_json" or "do_xlat" flag into the JSON ("avps"), and hope xlat will then dig deeper
3. Save the JSON and parse with exec/rlm_exec (using JQ or any other bash/JSON tools)

Please advise if there is any workaround. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In FreeRADIUS version 4, there's a rlm_json module, which implements a custom node query language based on xpath (jpath), it is extremely limited and only supports some very basic queries (feel free to enhance it via PR :) ).

Below is an example I pulled out of my library of customer configurations.  You can see here it's pulling out two keys (externalID and macAddress) from the root level of the JSON doc and assigning them to a couple of custom attributes (Subscriber-ID and Provisioned-MAC).

```
map json "%{rest_api:https://${modules.rest[rest_api].server}/admin/api/${modules.rest[rest_api].api_key}/external/getDeviceBySerialNumber?certificateSerialNumber=%{lpad:&TLS-Client-Cert-Serial 40 0}}" {
    &Subscriber-ID := '$.externalId'
    &Provisioned-MAC := '$.macAddress'
}
```

The xlat expansion can also be modified to send HTTP body data.  Just put a space after the URL and pass your custom JSON blob.

Comment: This looks great :)
However, our team is now using on rlm_rest.
The main reason is we had implement curl multi-interface to support HTTP/2 multiplexing in this case.

So I guess json must be the output of rlm_rest. Is there a way to pass the result of rlm_rest to rlm_json?

Comment: rest_api is just an instance of rlm_rest.  The expansion used there is the expansion from the rlm_rest module.  I think rlm_rest will support HTTP/2 fine.  Might need an extra option passed to libcurl to enable pipelining but that's about it.

Comment: Yeah I just checked this.  In v4.0.x at least we can add pipelining relatively easily.  Just need to set some options on the multi handle and we're good to go.

Comment: Thanks... 
I now noticed the implement of rlm_rest change from curl_easy to curl_multi_interface at FreeRADIUS 4.0.x. This does make HTTP/2 multiplexing relatively easy!

Comment: Anothor qeestion, how do i specify the HTTP method if I was gonna use "%{rest_api:https://REST_URI JSON_BODY"? I notice there is uri and body but no HTTP method.

Comment: et voilà! - https://github.com/FreeRADIUS/freeradius-server/commit/0b2ee1dcad86ebdee92e578034887662a9c1e3b2

Comment: Thanks for the generous help. Will use!

Comment: For the rest XLAT I believe you can use ``%{rest_api:HTTP_METHOD REST_URI JSON_BODY}``.

Comment: No problem! Let me know if anything needs tweaking.  Could you accept the answer if you think it's correct :)